# Как создать в приложении ссылку для просмотра документа на Google Drive?

Tags: php, google-drive

Возможно ли, и как создать ссылку для просмотра документа, который лежит на гугл диске, для показа на сайте? Использую Google API для взаимодействия сайта с диском, реализован CRUD по файлам, но не знаю как осуществить просмотр файла на моем сайте, не скачивая его.

Comment: [читаем api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get?) - я думаю по этому примеру станет всё совсем понятно

Comment: Читаем вопрос ("не знаю как осуществить просмотр файла на моем сайте, не скачивая его"), а в ссылке "Download a file's content."

Comment: Вы по ссылке смотрели пример? Введите попробуйте fileId и вам даст в ответе embedLink

Comment: спасибо, увидел.

Comment: Добавьте, как ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get?)  - там возвращает embedLink